# Using Thread Local Storage in a Dynamic-Link Library

Tags: dll, thread-local

i have a cross platform C++ project used thread_local variable ,and it will be provided in dll. this code works good in linux gcc,but in windows vc2019 platform ,it seems like i can not use `__declspec(dllexport)` and thread local together ，Or else it will generate

> [Compiler Error C2492]

this is from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2492?view=vs-2019)

code is a simple global int variable:

```
extern thread_local int threadid;
```

at last i get two wey:

first from [microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/dlls/using-thread-local-storage-in-a-dynamic-link-library) ,it is a little complicated.

second,do not declare thread_local variable in head file ,and use a get function to access it,like this:

```
#ifdef OS_WIN
DLL_EXPORT int getThreadId();
DLL_EXPORT threadLocalWrap& getThreadLocalWrap();
#else
extern thread_local int threadid;
extern thread_local threadLocalWrap _threadLocalWrap;
#define getThreadId() threadid
#define getThreadLocalWrap() _threadLocalWrap
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to use TLS in VS2019 is:

`#define Thread __declspec( thread )`

Them use in variable definition:

`Thread static int myVar;`